# Do I need to buy premium on Xbox if I have it on PC?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlefield-premium

If I buy xbox 360 version of BF4 when I have it on PC with premium, will I have premium access on xbox or do I need to buy it separately on xbox?

Comment: I don't think so. PC and Xbox are 2 different platforms. Most devs don't go the extra mile to give you premium stuff for different platforms unless you bought them on each of them. And then there's EA. Expect them to not give a sh*t about their customers; that's what they do best.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't have premium on XBOX and will need to buy premium for your XBOX version as well.  Cross-platform use of premium access is not granted; your accounts are linked (through Battlelog) but not to the point of using the same access level in both.

This has been further discussed [here](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/BF4-Premium-cross-platform/td-p/1853315).